# Functional way to evaluate boolean for a function that throws an exception

Tags: scala, exception, functional-programming

I'm trying to write the following function without using var and only val. Any ideas how to approach this ?

```
  def isValidBSONId(id: String): Boolean = {
    var valid: Boolean = false
    import reactivemongo.bson.utils.Converters._
    try {
      str2Hex(id)
      valid = true
    } catch  {
      case _ => valid = false
    }
    valid
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just `Try{}.isSuccess`

```
def isValidBSONId(id: String): Boolean = {
  import reactivemongo.bson.utils.Converters._
  Try(str2Hex(id)).isSuccess
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Wrap the call to `str2Hex(id)` in a `Try`, then pattern match on the results which are a `Success` or `Failure` case class. You can return true for the `Success` case or false for the `Failure` case. It might be preferable to just return the `Try` so the calling code doesn't have an if else block and can pattern match on the results which composes nicer.

```
def isValidBSONId(id: String): Boolean = {
  import reactivemongo.bson.utils.Converters._
  Try(str2Hex(id)) match {
    case Success(s) => true
    case Failure(e) => false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's just:

```
  def isValidBSONId(id: String): Boolean = {
    import reactivemongo.bson.utils.Converters._
    try {
      str2Hex(id)
      true
    } catch  {
      case _ =>  false
    }
  }
```

The last expression executed in a method or function becomes its return value. You should definitely catch the specific exception `str2Hex` throws if it fails, because there could be runtime errors you don't want to catch for these purposes.

It's a bit more idiomatic to use the [`Try` monad](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.10.2/index.html#scala.util.Try), which you might use as such:

```
  def checkBSONId(id: String): Try[String] = Try { str2Hex(id) }
```

Then you can do all sorts of interesting monadic stuff like `map` over or pattern match on the result.

Answer (score 0):

Consider also

```
def isValidBSONId(id: String): Boolean = 
  Try(reactivemongo.bson.utils.Convertersstr2Hex(id)) toOption != None
```

If `Try(str2Hex(id))` triggers an exception then `toOption` delivers `None`, hence from the inequality the method would return `false`, otherwise the method returns `true`.